# How to show form on button click?

Tags: android

I am making an android app where the user fills up a form. The client wants that out of many of the fields of the form, The user should see the compulsory fields first and then if the user wants then he/she should click on a button named as "More Fields (Optional)" and as soon as he clicks the button the button should disappear and then the user should see the other fields laid out one after the other.

The form looks like this now

[image: see the form here]

I have already tried setting the visibility of the edit Text to invisible, but the problem is that even if the text fields are invisible they take up most part of the screen.

I have been scrolling through the android forums but i got no hint as to how i can achieve it.

Comment: Put your children views in a scrollview(top-most) so that when your optional children views are visible, the layout would span and accommodate all the children.

Comment: Set the visibility to GONE, not INVISIBLE. Also put everything you want to hide/show toggle within its own LinearLayout/ScrollView and only toggle visibility on that section as a whole

Comment: Thanks for the help, I really appreciate  the quick response from your end, I'll definitely try putting the visibility to gone. :)

Comment: See the difference between invisible and gone

Answer (score 0):

It worked, I set the visibility to Gone and then everything happened as it was supposed to be.